# Tax based on currency in Opencart

Tags: opencart, currency

At present the tax seems to display based on the location of the logged in customer.

This can't work for me for 2 reasons. I have an extension that auto displays the currency based on the customers ip plus there is no option for logging in, it's guest checkout only.

So I really need it to display the correct price based on the currency displayed instead.

Does anyone have any idea where the code is for this please or how to adjust the displayed price properly?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

-James

Comment: Hi @jimbeeer. Have you managed to solve this? And how?

Comment: Hi @m1crdy. I'm racking my brain trying to remember how I sorted this issue (or even what I was originally trying to say!). Looking in my files I can see I purchased an opencart extension called 'Country to Currency' the day after I posted this. Perhaps that's the solution you're looking for? http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=445&filter_search=country%20currency

Answer (score 1):

I guess You should extend the extension You are using for displaying of currency based on IP address.

Find the line of code where the currency based on user's IP address is populated and call this:

```php
$this->currency->set($currency_code);
```

where `$currency_code` should be a 3 character currency ISO code (e.g. *USD*, *EUR*, etc) of currency set in the administration.

This way You set the currency to use for price calculation - and that reflects the currency based on user's IP address. This currency code is then saved to session and cookie so it should work on any page within OpenCart frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I think so

Returns 3-character ISO 4217 currency code for the currently set currency.

```
// Return when Pound Sterling is the set currency
$currency_code = $this->currency->getCode();
var_dump($currency_code); // string 'GBP' (length=3)
```

also you can

```
$this->currency->set($currency_code);
```

and please find currency file https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/currency.php

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the correct way to do this: Go to file system/library/tax.php.

Line 27:

```
if(!$reg){
            if($currentCurrency == "CHF"){
                $country_id = 204;
            }else if($currentCurrency == "EUR"){
                $country_id = 81;
            }
        }
```

This will set the country the user is in according to the selected currency and will set the country for tax calculation.